# How to convert object JSON to a d3.js array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, key-value-coding

I have the following dataset in JSON format which I want to convert to something I can work with in d3.js:

```
    {  
       "rank_type_1":{  
          "d1":0,
          "d2":1,
          "d3":2
       },
       "rank_type_2":{  
          "d1":1,
          "d2":0,
          "d3":2
       },
       "rank_type_3":{  
          "d1":2,
          "d2":0,
          "d3":1
       }
    }
```

I have 3 rank types according to which d1, d2 and d3 are ranked. Now, I want to convert it to the following format:

```
[
    {
     "id":d1
     "rank_type_1" :0
     "rank_type_2" :1
     "rank_type_3" :2
    },
    {
     "id":d2
     "rank_type_1" :1
     "rank_type_2" :0
     "rank_type_3" :2
    },
    {
     "id":d3
     "rank_type_1" :2
     "rank_type_2" :2
     "rank_type_3" :1
    }
]
```

The reason being that when I log the output of d3.csv function, it has a similar format. That is, it is an array of objects and the keys from the first object are converted into the values in the output array.

I have tried playing around with Object.entries, Object.keys, Object.values but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Object.keys()` and `forEach()` to loop object and add to array.

```js
var data = {"rank_type_1":{"d1":0,"d2":1,"d3":2},"rank_type_2":{"d1":1,"d2":0,"d3":2},"rank_type_3":{"d1":2,"d2":0,"d3":1}}

var result = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(e) {
  var that = this;
  Object.keys(data[e]).forEach(function(a) {
    if(!that[a]) {
      that[a] = {id: a, [e]: data[e][a]}
      result.push(that[a])
    } else {
      Object.assign(that[a], {[e]: data[e][a]})
    }
  })
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

Comment: great, thank you. 
Although, frankly speaking, I was expecting to get a "one-liner" :) Didn't expect it to be that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution using `Array#reduce`.

```js
var obj = {"rank_type_1":{"d1":0,"d2":1,"d3":2},"rank_type_2":{"d1":1,"d2":0,"d3":2},"rank_type_3":{"d1":2,"d2":0,"d3":1}}, 
    res = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(s,a,i) {
        var r = Object.keys(obj[a]).map((v, x) => ({["rank_type_"+[x+1]] : obj[a][v]})); 
        s.push(Object.assign({}, {id : "d"+(i+1)}, ...r));
        return s;
    }, []);

    console.log(res);
```